# Shapeless Lens Not Working Properly

Tags: scala, shapeless

I am trying to use a small snippet of Shapeless example code:

```
  import shapeless._

  case class Person(name : String, age : Int)
  val ageLens = lens[Person].age
  val person = Person("Joe Grey", 37)
  val person2 = ageLens.set(person)(38) // Error: Cannot find set method
```

**For some reason it cannot find the `set` method.  Why not?**

This code is straight from the examples here: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/lenses.scala

Comment: Your code works fine in my environment: Scala 2.11.7, Shapeless 2.2.5,  Java 1.8.0_45. Can you write your  build.sbt file, and sofware versions you are using ?

Comment: @ymonad Same specs.  Running SBT 0.13.8

Comment: @ymonad I ended up getting this to run, but intellJ is saying there is an error.  I think this might be an intelliJ bug.

Comment: Congrats. I should have ask "How did you get the error". I was using `vim` as editor and `sbt console` to check the behavior.

Comment: @ymonad Thanks.  I think you asked the right question.  This is the first time I have ever seen an IntelliJ error like this (I am on the EAP branch).